# Firefox, how to force a specific plugin (i.e. Java) to always load through 'click-to-play'?

Tags: firefox, java

After I've updated Java to version 7 update 17 it no longer activates 'click-to-play' when I am browsing to a site that uses Java.  I really like to put it back to 'click-to-play' list in light of Java security problems coming out weekly.

I know that you can turn on 'click-to-play' globally (for all plugins) through 'plugins.click_to_play' in 'about:config'.

However, I think it's a very blunt instrument.

I tried to find any documentation about 'click-to-play', but looks like it's really well hidden by Mozilla developers.

What I really would like to understand is where is the 'magic' block list of plugins maintained: locally, or on Mozilla web site?  If it is local, where is it?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure the feature is worth a whole tag just yet. [tag:firefox] is enough for now. You may also want to specify your Firefox version in the question body, though.

Comment: @Iszi 19.0 on Windows 7.

Comment: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20%28x86%29/Mozilla%20Firefox/blocklist.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "click to play"-functionality is still not completed. A per-addon / per-plugin blocking management via about:config or even a GUI seems not to be available.

As @Wk_of_Angmar already pointed out, the file `blocklist.xml` defines what is deemed unsafe by the browser. It is stored locally, but refreshed periodically(default: every 86400 seconds = daily) from the Mozilla servers; the behavior can be controlled by `Extensions.blocklist.interval`. If you now want your Java applets to be set to click to play, you would have to do three things:

1. Add an entry for your specific Java version in the blocklist file(Syntax [here](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Extension_Blocklisting:Code_Design), you should look into `pluginItem` specifically)
2. Prevent Firefox from updating the file and therefore overriding your entry. A possibility I could think of would be setting ´Extensions.blocklist.interval´ to a very high number or making the file read-only.
3. Remember to update the blocklist from the URL defined [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Extensions.blocklist.url) manually.

It is not pretty, but should work while CTP is still under development.